# Word to drink something quickly, as in 'down' or 'chug' a shot

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the act of drinking alcohol quickly / taking a shot. I need a *formal* (as these I deem informal) word akin to:

> He chugged the beer.
>
> She downed the shot.

*Imbibed* works generally in the context of alcohol but I don't think

> She imbibed the shot

is accurate in this context.

Comment: Socrates gulped his hemlock quietly, regretting only that he would miss the second season of *Peaky Blinders*.

Comment: This list may be helpful: [gulp synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/gulp?s=t). *Ingurgitate* seems formal enough.

Comment: "Gulp down" is about the best I can think of that is nominally formal and implies rapidly drinking the entire beverage.

Comment: *‘Wretch’, I cried, ‘Thy God has lent thee / By these angels He hath sent thee / Respite—respite and nepenthe from thy memories of Lenore! / Let me quaff this kind nepenthe and forget this lost Lenore!’*

Comment: Gordon Sculled his whiskey before Peaky Blinders.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***quaff***

> : to drink a large amount of (something) quickly.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quaff)
>
> *He quaffed the shot in one gulp, grimaced, and ordered another.*
>
> [Moonlight in Vermont: A Novel](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22restaurant+check+rack%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=ismvn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF3fqGyLnMAhUGDSwKHdOyC4wQ_AUIBSgA&dpr=2#q=%22quaffed+the+shot%22)

Comment: What an unusual usage. I wouldn't expect to see "quaff" used in relation to a single 25ml measure (a shot).

Answer (score 5):

Describing the physical action required as opposed to the act of consummation conjures an effective image. When consuming a shot glass of alcohol quickly you are not sipping or even slurping it; you put it to your lips and throw your head back to splash the liquid into your mouth as quickly as possible.

> He threw back a shot of whisky.

I don't know if that is within your scope of 'formal' but on the other hand, people aren't often 'throwing back a shot' at formal occasions.

Answer (score 2):

**ingurgitate**:

> to drink largely, to swig (*A Dictionary of the English Language,* By
>   Samuel Johnson and John Walker; accessed via [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=WBYwAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA390&dq=%22ingurgitate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyqN6oirrMAhXltoMKHeJYD3w4ChDoAQg5MAU#v=onepage&q=%22ingurgitate%22&f=false))

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingurgitate):

> to swallow greedily or in large quantities [...]
>
> **Did You Know?**
>   
> Most people are familiar with "regurgitate" as a fancy synonym for
>   "throw up," but far fewer know of its rarer antonym "ingurgitate."
>   It's a word as likely to turn up in a spelling bee as in a
>   conversation, but it does see occasional use, both literal (as in
>   "ingurgitating red wine") and figurative (as in "ingurgitating
>   artwork"). "Regurgitate" and "ingurgitate" (as well as "gurgitate," an
>   even rarer synonym of "ingurgitate," and gorge, meaning "to eat
>   greedily") can be ultimately traced back to the Latin word for
>   "whirlpool," which is "gurges."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[guzzle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/guzzle)*

> Eat or drink (something) greedily:
>
> *we guzzle our beer and devour our pizza*
>
> (figurative) *this car guzzles gas*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: I'm guessing that *guzzle* isn't considered "formal" enough.

Answer (score 0):

He Skulled the beer.

Common Australian idiom

Comment: Can you add some references?

Comment: I'm not sure that this fits the _formal_ requirement!

Comment: I think the word is ["scol" in AusEng](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/skol).

Answer (score 0):

In the immortal words of [Kinky Friedman](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8SfVfnwaeNMC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=%22killed%20the%20shot%22%20kinky&source=bl&ots=JtaPpl6Ej-&sig=LU_-9K_k5vyaltox4wIvJ-RYcZU&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22killed%20the%20shot%22%20kinky&f=false);

> *The aforementioned blower began ringing. **I killed the shot,** then
>   collared the instrument. First things first.*

Comment: The question specifically asked for a "formal" term; this is a highly colloquial usage.

Comment: @duskwuff - Because "quaff" is the more obviously formal? When OP accepted that, I felt that their request went straight out of the window.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree with the OP. "Quaff" has a very long history - it appears in Shakespeare! - and is hence treated as more formal than modern idioms like this one. While I agree that some of the connotations aren't quite right, it's certainly the best fit I see here.

Answer (score -1):

## bolt (vt)

> To eat hastily or without chewing.
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bolt)

Doesn't apply specifically to drinking, but would be appropriate.